# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GPIO'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I already installed GPIO in terminal and i want to import RPi.GPIO from GPIO to run L289n  but it do not work

Comment: did you google your problem?

Comment: of course ,but i did not find any solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not installed the module. Try

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-rpi.gpio
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-rpi.gpio

Comment: Try repository update before, I've added it to my answer.